# Как добавить кнопку поверх поля для ввода?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как добавить кнопку в строке ввода, чтобы это выглядело примерно так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Вот мой код:

```html
<div id="search">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Search U.K. house price data</h1>
            <form class="has-success has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="inputSearch">Search U.K. house price data</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Enter a postcode, street or address">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                <button class="btn" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Кнопка появляется снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] В чём проблема?
Как, вообще, примерно должен выглядеть код для всей строки?

Comment: Как вариант - [абсолютное позиционирование](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/pozitsionirovanie-elementov).

Comment: Т.е. справа, а не поверх

Comment: используйте позиционирование .btn {position:absolute; top: xx px; right: xx px; }

Comment: css : #search form {
 height: 60px;
 position: relative;
}


#search form input {
 border-radius: 30px;
 max-width: 970px;
 height: 60px;

}

#search h1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 background-size: cover;
}

.btn {
 height: 40px;
 width: 160px;
 background: url("../images/Rectangle-10-copy.png");
}

Comment: Вопрос помечен тегом bootstrap. В бутстрапе есть специальные классы для этого: **form-group** для оборачивания и **input-group-addon** для запихивания кнопок/значков на инпуты. Больше описания [здесь](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: И как же её всё-таки запихнуть?

Comment: <div class="container">
 <form>
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Enter a postcode, street or address">
   <span class="input-group-addon">SEARCH</span>
  </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>

Answer (score 4):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .4em;
  right: .4em;
  height: 2.2em;
  border-radius: 1.1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="....">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Вот полный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/philnicholas/XfzFQ/)

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
input[type="search"]{
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  padding: 5px 100px 5px 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
button[type="submit"]{
  position: absolute; top: 7px; right: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button[type="submit"]:hover{
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Text search" >
  <button type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1: Вы можете воспользоваться абсолютным позиционированием. Разместить кнопку поверх input с помощью z-index.

Вариант 2: Разместить кнопку справа от поля ввода, с помощью дизайна кнопки притвориться частью поля ввода.

Comment: и как код будет при этом выглядеть?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого существует [input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups), вам надо кастомизировать [button addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter address">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему у вас Search получился в рамке? Как в том месте вставить картинку? И чтобы она была не в рамке.

Comment: В рамке потому что это стандартные стили бутстрапа. Как вставить картинку не знаю.

Comment: Что-то не похоже на то, что в вопросе.